# How to change the Class ID of an ActiveX made in vb6

Tags: windows, windows-7, vb6, activex, uuid

I have an `ActiveX` control made in the vb6. Since the client is asking to change the class id and I have no knowledge of vb6, Please help me to determine the class id of an ActiveX.

I have searched a lot on the internet. but of no use.

In `C++` the `Class ID` is mentioned in the '`.idl`' file.
But in `vb6` I have no idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have VB6 and the source code available to rebuild the control?

Comment: Yes, @JimMack  I have both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you load the project into VB6, open `Project... Properties` and look at the Component tab. If the `Version Compatibility` is set to `Binary`, VB will attempt to keep the same CLSID (assuming it has a model). If you change this to `No Compatibility`, or if you change the interface, VB will assign a new CLSID when you compile.

Comment: @Bundle of thanks, It worked. but how to determine new class id in the Windows Registry?

Comment: @ImranKhanHunzai One way is to register it using Regsvr32 and search the CLSIDs in the registry for the public name. You can unregister it when done if that's an issue. I believe you could also use RegHacker to look at the EXE, but the CLSID would not be in a 'friendly' format. There may be a more straightforward way, but I've never had to do this, so...

Comment: You can also use the  OLE View tool that ships with VB6 to examine the compiled DLL/OCX's typelib.  The format shown is in MIDL syntax.

Comment: Another way would be to start a new project, include the AX as a reference or component, save the project and open the VBP in a text viewer. The CLSID will be listed there. Note that doing this will have the side-effect of registering the component, if that matters.